# How to avoid occurring many AsyncTask class in my Android Room repository?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I'm learning how to use Android Room from [google-developer-training](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-7-working-with-architecture-components/lesson-15-room,-livedata,-viewmodel/15-1-a-room-livedata-viewmodel/15-1-a-room-livedata-viewmodel.html#task6intro), where I found example of `repository class`. I try to simplify my `SportRepository` class. I wonder how to avoid repetition of `inner class ...AsyncTask` in my code. Here is very sample example:

```
@Singleton
class SportRepository {
    val LOG_TAG = SportRepository::class.java.name

    @Inject
    lateinit var sportDAO: SportDAO
    var list: LiveData<List<Sport>>

    init {
        App.app().appComponent()?.inject(this)
        list = sportDAO.getAll()
    }

    fun insert(sport: Sport) {
        insertAsyncTask().execute(sport)
    }

    fun update(sport: Sport){
        updateAsyncTask().execute(sport)
    }

    fun delete(sport: Sport) {
        deleteAsyncTask().execute(sport)
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private inner class insertAsyncTask() : AsyncTask<Sport, Void, Void>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Sport): Void? {
            sportDAO.insert(p0.get(0))
            return null
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private inner class updateAsyncTask() : AsyncTask<Sport, Void, Void>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Sport): Void? {
            sportDAO.update(p0[0])
            return null
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private inner class deleteAsyncTask() : AsyncTask<Sport, Void, Void>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Sport): Void? {
            sportDAO.delete(p0[0])
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

The `AsyncTask` classes differ only in name and in kind of method invoke from sportDAO class.

**Is there any way to avoid creating many almost the same `AsyncTask` classes?**

I've not found any example how to simplify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I faced the same. There are 3 solutions that I use.
 1. Use RX. Return a Flowable, and observe it on different thread.
 2. Use LiveData.
 3. Async Task. This is how I avoid multiple async tasks by using Generics. I hope this is what you are looking for.

This is the class that will perform your queries.

```
/**
 *
 * @param <T> type of result expected
 */
public abstract class DaoAsyncProcessor<T> {

    public interface DaoProcessCallback<T>{
        void  onResult(T result);
    }

    private DaoProcessCallback daoProcessCallback;

    public DaoAsyncProcessor(DaoProcessCallback daoProcessCallback) {
        this.daoProcessCallback = daoProcessCallback;
    }

    protected abstract T doAsync();

    public void start(){
        new DaoProcessAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    private class DaoProcessAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, T>{

        @Override
        protected T doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return doAsync();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(T t) {
            if(daoProcessCallback != null)
                daoProcessCallback.onResult(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Now for querying

```
fun putAllUsersAsync(vararg users: User) {
            object : DaoAsyncProcessor<Unit>(null) {
                override fun doAsync(): Unit {
                    yourDao.insertAll(*users)
                }

            }.start()
        }
```

Another example of fetching data.

```
fun getAllUsers(callback: DaoAsyncProcessor.DaoProcessCallback<List<User>>) {
            object : DaoAsyncProcessor<List<User>>(callback) {
                override fun doAsync(): List<User> {
                    return yourDao.getAll()
                }

            }.start()
```

You can call getAllUsers and pass a callback for getting the data.

As requested, this is the Kotlin equivalent

```
abstract class DaoAsyncProcessor<T>(val daoProcessCallback: DaoProcessCallback<T>?) {

    interface DaoProcessCallback<T> {
        fun onResult(result: T)
    }


    protected abstract fun doAsync(): T

    fun start() {
        DaoProcessAsyncTask().execute()
    }

    private inner class DaoProcessAsyncTask : AsyncTask<Void, Void, T>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): T {
            return doAsync()
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(t: T) {
            daoProcessCallback?.onResult(t)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, however, Android Studio says that DaoProcessAsyncTask should be static.

Comment: That's because I think you have made it an inner class

Comment: When I try to convert class `DaoAsyncProcessor`, I stuck on the problem with `onPostExecute(T t)` method. I get the message from IDE:


`Out-projected type 'DaoAsyncProcessor.DaoProcessCallback<*>' prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun onResult(result: T): Unit`.  Please provide Kotlin code for this class or tell how to solve this?

Comment: @wapn adding the kotlin equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Using RX java you could replace AsyncTask with a Completable for your insert/update/delete commands.

```
fun insert(sport: Sport) : Completable = Completable.fromAction { sportDAO.insert(sport) }
fun update(sport: Sport) : Completable = Completable.fromAction { sportDAO.update(sport) }
fun delete(sport: Sport) : Completable = Completable.fromAction { sportDAO.delete(sport) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same AsyncTask for each task if you pass it the code segment that it needs to actually execute.

You could for example do the following, using `lambda-with-receivers` (and without having to add Rx completables/singles or whatever):

```
@Singleton
class SportRepository @Inject constructor(val sportDAO: SportDao) {
    companion object {
        const val LOG_TAG = "SportRepository"
    }

    var list: LiveData<List<Sport>> = sportDAO.getAll() // is this necessary?

    fun insert(sport: Sport) {
        executeTask(sport) { insert(it) }
    }

    fun update(sport: Sport){
        executeTask(sport) { update(it) }
    }

    fun delete(sport: Sport) {
        executeTask(sport) { delete(it) }
    }

    private fun executeTask(sport: Sport, task: SportDao.(Sport) -> Unit) {
        BackgroundTask(sport, task).execute()
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private inner class BackgroundTask(
        private val sport: Sport,
        private val task: SportDao.(Sport) -> Unit
    ) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void): Void? {
            task(sportDAO, sport)
            return null
        }
    }
}
```